# After moving my app from Eclipse to Studio 0.2.1, a screen rotate causes the app to malfunction

Tags: android, eclipse

After moving my app from Eclipse to Studio 0.2.1, a screen rotate causes the app to malfunction.

I want my app to support both landscape and portrait on Nexus7 (and larger), and the Samsung Galaxy S4, and smaller devices (if possible).

The AndroidManifest.xml files are identical.

The app fails identically from land>port and port>land.

When rotating the screen, the following methods are invoked:

- onSaveInstanceState;
- onStop;
- OnDestroy.

The app also contains both onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, but I don't have the foggiest idea what code needs to be placed in these methods.

OnDestroy cantains the code: 
        "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())".

I would like to remove the ...killProcess... code and have my app execute according to the Android Life Cycle guide lines, if possible.

But, if I remove the ...killProcess... code, when manually rotating the screen the Action Bar is filled with as many Menu Items as it will hold (on both Eclipse and Studio 0.2.1). I tried many combinations of manifest changes and code changes before resorting to the ...killProcess... code.

Android version 4.3 was loaded onto my Nexus7 the evening of 7/26/2013.  My test on the morning of 7/27/2013 produced the same results.

I hope that I won't have to port back to Eclipse, since Android Studio is the best development environment on the planet.

Thanks in advance.

Below find some relevant code:

```
/**  Start Processing  */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**  Don't know what this does !!  */
    //ActionMode mActionMode;
    // mSearchText = new TextView(this);
    // setContentView(mSearchText);
    //ActionMode mContextMode = startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);


    /** Set up openGL environment */
    setContentView(R.layout.vjn_menu);
    mGLSurfaceView = (VjnGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl_surface_view);


    // Check if the system supports OpenGL ES 2.0.
    final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)  getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final ConfigurationInfo configurationInfo = activityManager.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    final boolean supportsEs2 = configurationInfo.reqGlEsVersion >= 0x20000;

    if (supportsEs2)
    {
        // Request an OpenGL ES 2.0 compatible context.
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        // Set the renderer.
        mRenderer = new VjnRenderer(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer, displayMetrics.density);
    }
}

/**
 * onResume notifies OpenGL of resume event.
 */
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    /**  Restore preferences  */
    getPrefs();

    /***  Disabled --------------
    if(mStopped && mActions == "<>")
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "PREFS_NAME NOT changed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "PREFS_NAME CHANGED from default.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
     ---------------*/

    super.onResume();
    mGLSurfaceView.onResume();

    return;
}


/**
 * onPause notifies OpenGL of pause event.
 */
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    return;

}
/**
 * onStop saves this method's preferences.
 */
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    putPrefs(PREFS_NAME);  // Commit Preferences

    return;
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    putPrefs(PREFS_NAME);  // Commit Preferences
    Toast.makeText(this, "onSaveInstanceState entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRestoreInstanceState entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    return;
}

public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onConfigurationChanged entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}

/**  Create Options Menu  */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    try
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
    }
    catch (InflateException e)
    { // Number not a floating point number
        Toast.makeText(this, "InflateException in onCreateOptionsMenu.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    /**  Save original Action Bar titles for later use  */
    if (! onPrepare) // Have we prepared for this menu?
    { // Prime ActionBar control for Object (model, assembly & sub-assembly)
        onPrepare = true;  // First time through onPrepareOptionMenu: Done
        ActionBar.DefineVisibility(menu);  // True logic

        /**  First time processing: activate GoTo menu structure ---------------------- */
        int[] mGoToVis = { ABgoTo, 1 };
        boolean mReturn1 = ActionBar.OnlyVisible(mGoToVis);
        if (!mReturn1) // Success?
        { // No
            Toast.makeText(this, "onPrepareOptionsMenu, SetVisibility error 1.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        //ActionBar.DisableTools();

    }

    /**  Always activate GoTo menu structure ---------------------- */
    int[] mGoToVis = { ABgoTo, 1 };
    int[] mReturn1 = ActionBar.SetVisibility(mGoToVis);
    if (mReturn1[0] == (-1)) // Success?
    { // No
        Toast.makeText(this, "onPrepareOptionsMenu, SetVisibility error 1.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /**  Control the visibility of Action Bar GoTo menus  */
    if (mIsModelValid) // Is Model ID valid?
    { // Yes, set "Tools", "Object" and "Magnifying Glass" visible

    } else
    { // No, set "Object" and "Magnifying Glass" visible
        int[] mModelInvalid = {ABobject, 1};
        int[] mReturn2 = ActionBar.SetVisibility(mModelInvalid);
        if (mReturn2[0] == (-1)) // Success?
        { // No
            Toast.makeText(this, "onPrepareOptionsMenu, SetVisibility error 2.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    .
    .
    .


    /**  TEST:  if we stopped last execution, disable & set not visible "Tools"
     if (m2ndPass)
     {
     boolean mDtStatus = ActionBar.DisableTools();
     if (! mDtStatus)
     {
     Toast.makeText(this, "DisableTools failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
     Toast.makeText(this, "DisableTools SUCCESS!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     }
     ------------ */

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

} // End of onPrepareOptionsMenu

protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRestoreInstanceState entered.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}






<!-- SORT menu follows  -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_sort"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size"
      android:title="@string/action_bar_sort"
      android:showAsAction="never">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_size"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size"
              android:title="@string/action_bar_sort_size"
              android:onClick="onSort" />

        <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_alpha"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_alphabetically"
              android:title="@string/action_bar_sort_alpha"
              android:onClick="onSort" />
    </menu>
</item>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ghyrome.objectworld1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ow_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.ghyrome.objectworld1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <module external.system.id="GRADLE" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
   <component name="FacetManager">
     <facet type="android" name="Android">
     <configuration>
    <option name="SELECTED_BUILD_VARIANT" value="Debug" />
    <option name="ASSEMBLE_TASK_NAME" value="assembleDebug" />
    <option name="ASSEMBLE_TEST_TASK_NAME" value="assembleTest" />
    <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
    <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
    <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/res" />
    <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/src/main/assets" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
<facet type="android-gradle" name="Android-Gradle">
  <configuration>
    <option name="GRADLE_PROJECT_PATH" value=":ObjectWorld1" />
  </configuration>
</facet>
 </component>
 <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="false">
<output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes/debug" />
<exclude-output />
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/debug" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/r/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/aidl/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/rs/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source/buildConfig/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/res/rs/test" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/assets" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/jni" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/rs" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/res" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/debug/resources" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/aidl" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/assets" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/jni" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/rs" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/res" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" isTestSource="false" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/aidl" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/assets" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/java" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/jni" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/rs" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/res" isTestSource="true" />
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/instrumentTest/resources" isTestSource="true" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/apk" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/assets" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/bundles" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/classes" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/dependency-cache" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/exploded-bundles" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/incremental" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/libs" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/manifests" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/symbols" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/tmp" />
</content>
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android 4.2.2 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
<orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="support-v4-13.0.0" level="project" />
  </component>
  </module>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.ghyrome.objectworld1.VjnGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/gl_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please show some relevant code. You definitely should not be using killProcess.  Is the ActionBar the only problem?

Comment: From the submitter: There was a mistake in the Manifest > application > activity--pre-mature end (">") of activity.  Sorry.